# Python interpreter 3.7.1 does not print None value when it must be returned by a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am surprised for days my Python interpreter does not print `None` anymore while a function must return this value.

```
(base) avy@mohaha:~$ python
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:28:38) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def machin(arg):
...     if arg == 1:
...             return 9
...     else:
...             return None
... 
>>> machin(1)
9
>>> machin(2)
>>> machin(1) == None
False
>>> machin(2) == None
True
```

It did not do that before. Is it a matter of updates, settings of Python? Honestly I did nothing by myself to modify the interpreter.
That's disturbing, what should I do?

Even if this is normal by designed as some said, that's still strange for me. A function does not necessarilly return something. This behaviour above is what I expect from a function that has not output (`return something`). When it must return something, and that I expect `None`, I want to see this result, because it does not return nothing it returns `None`. That's more explicit.

Notes: Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.7.1

Comment: I don't see the unusual or new behaviour in your example. `None` is the default return for functions with no explicit return, such as `def f(args): pass`. So it is ignored by the return printing call.

Comment: It's actually an echo and not a print, and when told to echo None it ignores it. Try typing None in the interactive promt for example.

Comment: @Learningisamess before it did print the None in shell. I am not kidding, I was searching for a bug in my previous scrapy shell sessions because it was not print or echo.

Comment: Did you change it from `print(None)`?

Comment: To be clear, [this is a configurable behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook). Is it possible you were running with a Python wrapper that replaced `sys.displayhook`? The default behavior is to suppress `None` output, but a replacement can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I did not see that thing. Thanks.

Comment: "A function does not necessarilly return something." Well, actually it does. A function in Python *always* has a return value. If you do not return a value explicitly, the function will implicitly return `None`. The interactive REPL simply suppresses `None` outputs, for convenience mainly, because many methods, for example, `my_list.append('foo')` returns `None`, and it clutters the session. But you can explicitly `print` it and it will print `None`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok. So it means to write `else: None` is totally useless, right?

Comment: @AvyWam well, there's nothing wrong with being explicit about it. So, while it strictly isn't necessary, it does make your intent clear

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: That said, variable return types are usually a sign of code smell; if you think you need to return one type normally, and `None` under "bad" conditions, you should probably be using exceptions instead. The exception being cases where the "bad" condition is normal/expected (e.g. `re.match` failing to match a string), but uncommon "bad" conditions should almost always be exceptions.